# Why is a BlockIndexState model required when using demux.js?

Tags: dapp, javascript

I was checking the project [eosio-project-demux-example](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example) since I want to use **demux.js** in my own project. I have doubts about the mongoose model BlockIndexState.

I would like to know what is it used for. Is it required? Is it for querying? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlockIndexState, is a mongoose defined schema, where dapp know about the processed blocks, 
Demux watch the node block from particular defined block[ eg:153343 https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js#example, check `NodeosActionReader` ] block and store the state of block that being watched and continue from that point.

```
async updateIndexState (state, block, isReplay) {
const { blockInfo } = block
try {
  await state.blockIndexState.update({}, {
    blockNumber: blockInfo.blockNumber,
    blockHash: blockInfo.blockHash,
    isReplay
  }, { upsert: true }).exec()
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
}

async loadIndexState () {
try {
  let blockHash
  let blockNumber
  const indexState = await BlockIndexState.findOne({}).exec()
  if (indexState) {
    ({ blockHash, blockNumber } = indexState)
  }
  if (blockNumber && blockHash) {
    return { blockNumber, blockHash }
  }
  return { blockNumber: 0, blockHash: '' }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

one can clearly see that updateIndexState,loadIndexState alters/reads BlockIndexState

references
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example/issues/31

Comment: Can you suggest me some source so  that i can learn demux and use in my project.

Comment: Yes most of the github examples are mocking EOS main project,I am planning to give a demo soon . I struggled a lot at first ,now I am comfortable with it.I'll get you know